JLabel Updating with the Contents of another Control
This should be ridiculously simple. My code runs through a folder listing and counting files. When I update the file count label, the contents of my files list populates the display of the label. Yet if I System.out.println getText of the file count label, the output is correct. It's just the display that is wonky.

My code is pretty straight forward:
public void incrementFilesProcessedCount() {
    filesProcessedCount++;
    this.lblFilesProcessedCount.setText(Integer.toString(filesProcessedCount));
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(filesProcessedCount)); //correct output
    System.out.println(this.lblFilesProcessedCount.getText()); //correct output that matches the output of above.
}


Why would you try to set a long list of names as the text of a JLabel? At the very least, that would mean it should be in a scroll pane

Are you calling incrementFilesProcessedCount on the EDT? (Event Dispatching Thread) If so, your problem is that because you are processing on the EDT, the screen cannot be updated. If not, try calling this.lblFilesProcessedCount.repaint().

g00se - I'm not. I'm adding an integer only. The GUI is taking the list above and inserting it into the label.

ControlAltDel - Tried the repaint. it made no difference. It should be running on the EDT. The append log that populates the list above it is as well. It is working perfectly. NOTE the value I am passing with setText is actually there and correct. I figured that out by making it red. It was indeed there, so it is the background of the label that is getting hosed. However, I did try to override that by setting the background to the same blue after setting the text and that had no effect.

That's weird. I haven't seen that kind of bork before. But My code runs through a folder listing and counting files should not be done on the EDT. That should be done in a dedicated thread and the only things done on the EDT are updates to the components. Use SwingWorker @ControlAltDel is right

G00se - Then I misspoke. It is running in a SwingWorker. I did however, change it to a text field instead of a label, changed the format to match the background, got rid of the border, set editable to false as well as made it set the highlighter to null.  Using a label should have saved a bunch of steps, but that issue was holding me up for way too long. No issues with using a JTextField instead. Just more on the initial setup side of things.

You haven't got a null layout have you by any chance?

g00se - I think I figured it out. When I moved the app to another computer the problem reared it's head again on label that weren't being updated. After digging into it, I realized what was happening. For certain controls and containers, I was setting the background color with 4 values R, B, G and A. Evidently the Alpha channel on those was giving the issues. When I went with no alpha value in the color - just 3 values of RGB - the issue went away and everything was as expected.

Right. Glad you sorted it out.
